Ast module for kdb sql queries
I want to analyze the code structure of a nested kdb+ queries just like what python ast module does to the python codes.
I know that kdb "parse" function already does this in kdb, but how I can implement such functionality in python, so that I can loop through all the syntax tree nodes in the sql query, and make my own custom analysis and change.
For example:
parse "select avg close by date from update close+100 from table"

will get
?
(!;`table;();0b;(,`close)!,(+;`close;100))
()
(,`date)!,`date
(,`close)!,(avg;`close)

I want it to be a tree object in python to be able to modify myself.
